# UINavigationController to Hold previous ViewController in a different Tab

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to create a global navigation stack. When the user changes tabs or navigates to a new view in the same tab, I want to push the new view onto the global navigation stack. I want the back button in the navigation bar to go back to the previous view, which is sometimes a different tab, and sometimes a different view in the same tab.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand you have 5 navigation controllers and one tabbar controller and what you described is about the vice-versa configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring it is just a tab change but it does it programatically, and when the back is pressed it selects the previous tab programatically.

Here's the simple code to change the tab, I hope this would help you to build your logic.

Set selectedViewController:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = viewControllerYouWant;
```

For example,

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
```

UPDATES :

Adding left bar button to navigation controller,UIBarButtonItem *customItem =

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:bttnImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
[self.navigationController setHidesBackButton:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: customItem];
```

Comment: but by using this method the navigation controller does't display the back bar button

Comment: Obviously it will not display, back bar button, because it is first controller in navigation stack, I am updating the answer to add the back bar button, this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global navigationController and  a custom fake tabbar which to change the global navigationController content while switch the tabbar index.